# How to add MS Visual Studio 2017 C# missing Excel Reference after download?

Tags: c#, excel, add-references-dialog

I am discovering C# in MS Visual Studio 2017 but I cannot add the required MS Excel reference due to the fact that it is not availble. As you can see in the attached --> [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7LV1.jpg)

Could somebody help me explain how to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You have excel installed on your machine? And currently you are looking only for reference in your solution. you should got to the "browse" section which will also list assemblies from your global assembly cache (GAC) or will let you search manually for your desired dll.

Comment: Expand "References" in your project. Which Reference exactly shows a yellow warning symbol? A screenshot with an empty window is not very informative. How does the partly hidden "using Excel = Mi..." read exactly?